# Extracting result of Regular Expression using R in Power BI

Tags: r, powerbi, powerquery

I've spent all day on this and don't feel any closer to achieving what I need. I don't really understand R or Python. I have a use case where I'm expecting to need to search a field for a specific unique ID. My data looks like the below:

[image: EpicTriffid_0-1687963019622.png]

In this case, I need to extract where is says 55133025_Preq_1. The ID will change in the future, but that is the basic format it will appear in. 8 digits, an underscore, a few letters (which will be either pReq or DCTReq), and underscore, then a number that will gradually increase over time. I have the regular expression, which is "[0-9]+*[A-Za-z]+*[0-9]+"

Using the following R script, I have gotten to the point where i can identify those fields with the ID in them:

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
pattern <- "[0-9]+_[A-Za-z]+_[0-9]+"
hasUID <- function(x) {grepl(pattern, as.character(x), ignore.case=TRUE)}
output <- within(dataset,{UID=hasUID(dataset$Column1)})
```

Which gives me:

[image]

Now what I need is for the new column to actually contain the extracted ID, not just to tell me if it exists in the field. This is what I just cannot get it to do. I am aware there is the Javascript method, but this is a report that will be in the Power BI Service, meaning I can't use that method. I am happy to use Python, but i know even less about that than I do R.

Any help is much much appreciated.

[Edit]

Following on advice in the comments, I know use the following code and get the following result:

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
pattern <- ".*([0-9]+_[A-Za-z]+_[0-9]+).*"
getUID <- function(x) {ifelse(grepl(pattern, as.character(x), ignore.case=TRUE), x, NA)}
output <- within(dataset,{UID=getUID(dataset$Column1)})
```

[image]

So I need the result of the regex to be separated out of those rows where there is other text.

Thank you so much for your help @I_O

[Edit 2]

I have now gotten it to work by using both the gsub and grepl methods, by check for the TRUE and FALSE, then extracting the value, and using a conditional column set all instances that are TRUE to the output, else null. However, I'm trying to improve it and reduce the steps by integrating them into one R script, but I can't get this to work?

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script 
pattern <- ".*([0-9]+{8}_[A-Za-z]+_[0-9]+).*"
UIDcheck <- function(x) {grepl(pattern, as.character(x), ignore.case=TRUE)}
getUID <- function(x) {gsub(pattern, "\\1", x)}
finalCheck <- function (x) {ifelse(isTRUE(UIDcheck), getUID, NA)}
output <- within(dataset,{UID=finalCheck(dataset$SearchColumn)})
```

Comment: 1. wrap your pattern in parentheses and add leading and trailing catch-all expressions: `pattern <- ".*([0-9]+_[A-Za-z]+_[0-9]+).*"` 2. return the matching group (the part in parenthesis) like this: `getUID <- function(x) gsub(pattern, "\\1", x) `

Comment: I changed my code, like you said, to the below, but it now seems to pull only a portion of the string, like "5_Preq_20", as well as pulling items in other rows, like the "33": 

`# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
pattern <- ".*([0-9]+_[A-Za-z]+_[0-9]+).*"
getUID <- function(x) gsub(pattern, "\\1", x)
output <- within(dataset,{UID=getUID(dataset$Column1)})`

I'd post a picture, but i don't know how in comments

Comment: To return the whole content, not only the match, try `getUID <- function(x) {ifelse(grepl(pattern, as.character(x), ignore.case=TRUE), x, NA)}`. And, no, don't post pictures of code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors ;-)

Comment: Ah, got you. It was more going to be a picture to illustrate what had been returned.

As for this, we're getting closer. I need to post a picture, so will add it as an edit to my original post

Comment: Can't you just filter the final column to remove nulls using the drop down filter arrow atop that column?

Comment: I feel like I'm not being very clear. Sorry for that. I only want to return values like "55133025_PReq_1". So from the above example of "Foundation - C.Snape55254025_Preq_20", I would want "55254025_Preq_20".